# Why does Ubuntu store the daemon logs on /var/log/daemon.log.1 instead of /var/log/daemon.log?

Tags: ubuntu, logs, daemon

Trying to `cat /var/log/daemon.log` doesn't produce any output, while `cat /var/log/daemon.log.1` does. Why do daemons store logs to the **/var/log/daemon.log.1** file instead of **/var/log/daemon.log**? Is there a specific reason they are storing on the other file?

**NOTE:** `ls -l /var/log` shows both of those files have the same permissions and both are owned by a user called `admin`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*.1`, `*.2.gz`, etc. files are generated by `logrotate`, normally invoked by `cron` once a day IIRC.  `logrotate` is designed to prevent log files from getting too large.  It `gzip`s the file after "1".  Programs won't write to the `*.1`, etc. files on their own.

Are you sure that `/var/log/daemon.log.1` is receiving new data?  What's the timestamp of the last line in the file?

It sounds like your `syslog` process is not running or has crashed.  Did you run out of disk space?

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer, there is a `/var/log/daemon.log.2` file too. I am not running out of space on the computer i noticed this behavior. However, I am now using another computer, again with Ubuntu 12.04 as the main OS, and I noticed that it doesn't have a `/var/log/daemon.log` at all.

Comment: Well, I'm using Debian, of which Ubuntu is a derivation.  Perhaps Ubuntu is using something different with logging now.